# Get running time for azure VMs

Tags: azure

I need to know Vm's running time in Azure by month

Is this possible without seeing in Log Analytics? Because we have only free version

Can I see from Cost Billing?

Comment: I would checkout [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/download-azure-invoice-daily-usage-date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/download-azure-invoice-daily-usage-date).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the cost breakdown under Cost Management in Azure Portal

In the Azure portal, navigate to cost analysis for your scope.

For example: `Cost Management + Billing > Cost Management > Cost analysis.` Select Cost by **`resource`**. Change the view to Table.

Also i would recommend you to go through these [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/)

Comment: But I dont see the column where it says the running time of the vm

Comment: unless if its a devtest lab it should be 730 hours